# This comment is valid but there is no way to post it

Tags: discussion, comments

There is a minimum 15 character limit on posting a comment. There are shorthand features provided by the chat formatting utilities such as [ask] get expanded to **How to Ask** which is linked to url.

But following can't be posted as comment, as it lacks the length validation

```
See [ask].
```

It expands to

```
See How to Ask.
```

As, I can't post this comment, I do need to include some other character's/ word and most often ...... (dots) . I don't say that is a pain, but this can be taken care of while validating the comment.

So, I think there must be a minimum pre-parsing to check if the final expansion meet the length criteria or not. Similar applies while posting "See [answer]" as comment.

Comment: `You might want to have a look at the [ask] page on this site`

Comment: `Please have a look at [ask].`

Comment: @Bart I didn't got the meaning of your comment. Do you want to say, I should search for it on meta and saying this post is a duplicate. Please clarify

Comment: @mtk: They're providing examples of how you could phrase the comment to pass the minimum character limit.

Comment: @mtk: He means that instead of writing `See [ask]......`, you could also pad it with something useful. *See [ask]* might pass the 15 char limit, but it isn't exactly a great comment.

Comment: @mtk I hope my answer somewhat clears this up for you.

Comment: It can be something else but still short like 'Check [ask]'.

Comment: @mtk That still has the same problem. Put some effort into your comments. It's not all that hard and might be more appreciated by the recipient.

Comment: @mtk: Unless the user asked where he can find a page with information on how to post a question, that's not much better. Although you're trying to be helpful (I assume), this sounds very unfriendly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion "See How to Ask." is not a good comment. (Not the worst of comments either of course) Sure, it is made with the best intentions and links to valuable information. But it might read as a somewhat unfriendly demand.

It is easily rephrased as

> You might want to have a look at the [ask] page on this site

which in my opinion reads somewhat friendlier. And it doesn't take all that much effort.

In general I don't really see the point in adding a feature to take such expansion of links into account. I can't think of a situation in which it would be too much effort to simply rephrase what you're trying to say to meet the character limit.

Comment: Yes, the whole point of these shortcuts is to help you *explain more* in the comment without hitting the character maximum, not to type less.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks :)